# spring boot mongo with CommonMongoRepository but Error Help Me

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to create a simple CRUD Common Repository utilizing spring boot mongo.

However, an error occurred and it has not been resolved for 3 days. This is my source code.

0. MemberDTO.java

   ```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Document(collection = "member")
    public class MemberDTO {


        @Id
        private String memberId;

        private String memberPwd;

        private String memberName;

        private String memberEName;


    }
   ```
1. MemberController.java

   ```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/member")
    public class MemberController {


        @Autowired
        private MemberSv memberSv;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String member_save(MemberDTO memberDTO)
        {
            memberSv.member_save(memberDTO);
            return "join_form";
        }
    }
   ```
2. MemberSvImp.java

   ```
    @Service
    public class MemberSvImp{

        @Autowired
        private MemberSv memberSv;

        public MemberDTO member_save(MemberDTO memberDTO) {
            memberSv.save(memberDTO);
            return memberDTO;
        }

    }
   ```
3. MemberSv.java

   ```
    public interface MemberSv extends CommonRepository<MemberDTO, String> {


        MemberDTO member_save(MemberDTO memberDTO);

    }
   ```
4. CommonRepository.java

   ```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface CommonRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends         MongoRepository<T, ID> {

        <E extends T> E save(E entity);
    }
   ```
5. Error...
   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating
   bean with name 'memberController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
   'memberSv'; nested exception is
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
   name 'memberSv' defined in com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv
   defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on AccountProjectApplication:
   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
   org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not
   create query
   for public abstract com.example.accountproject.documents.MemberDTO .accountproj
   ect.documents.MemberDTO)! Reason: No property member found for type MemberDTO!
   Did you mean 'memberId'?; nested exception is
   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property member
   found for type MemberDTO! Did you mean 'memberId'?

Comment: I think you need @Repository in MemberSv.java to Spring know it is a repo component.

Comment: I added @Repositroy, but the same error.

Comment: (1) Follow Java naming conventions. This is always a good idea but is mandatory for automatic Spring Data repositories. (2) Why are you inventing your own instead of using `CrudRepository`?

Comment: It's because we want to use save as one no matter what document comes in common.

Comment: @DBK Try removing the `member_save` method from `MemberSv.java`. JPA might be trying to resolve the query through the method name.

Comment: @DBK And better you have the understanding that there are its own pros and cons saving documents with different types in the same collection. You can find some good read in this [Question](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/store-data-in-a-single-collection-or-multiple-collections/102261/2) in MongoDB community forum and in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202394/is-it-possible-to-store-multiple-types-of-objects-into-1-mongodb-collection) in here.